# BrowserRouter appending to Express API call

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-redux, react-router-dom

First time asker here.

So I'm building an API with express/mongo/react/redux and I'm having some problems with BrowserRouter. Here's my React routing:

```
 <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
 <Route path="/account/change-password/:hash" component={ChangePasswordPage} />
 <Route exact path="/account/login" component={LoginPage} />
 <Route path="/account/profile/:id" component={ProfilePage} />
 <Route exact path="/account/register" component={RegisterPage} />
 <Route exact path="/account/registration-success" component={RegistrationSuccessPage} />
 <Route exact path="/account/reset-password" component={ResetPasswordPage} />
 <Route exact path="/sources/sourcelist" component={SourceListPage} />
 <Route path="/sources/:sourcename" component={SourcePage} />
```

and from app.js:

```
const api = require('./routes/api/index');
const authentication = require('./routes/api/authentication');
const index = require('./routes/index');
const sources = require('./routes/api/sources');
const users = require('./routes/api/users');
const User = require('./models/user');
// Some Stuff
app.use('/api', api);
app.use('/api/sources', sources);
app.use('/api/users', users);
app.use('/api/authentication', authentication);
app.use('/*', index);
```

Then in api/routes/sources.js (which works, it returns the json object and passes it to the redux store, no problems there):

```
 router.get('/sourcelist', async (req, res) => {
    // Create query
    const query = Source
     .find({})
    .select('source')
    .sort({ source: 1 });
  const sources = await query.exec();

  if (sources) {
    return res.json({ sources });
  }
  return res.json({ error: 'There was an error finding the source list.' });
 });
```

And lastly: the redux action which calls the whole thing:

```
// Populate source data
export function populateSourceList() {
  return async (dispatch) => {
// clear the error box if displayed
dispatch(clearError());

// turn on spinner
dispatch(incrementProgress());

// Hit the API
await fetch(
  'api/sources/sourcelist',
  {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    credentials: 'same-origin',
  },
)
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.status === 200) {
      return response.json();
    }
    return null;
  })
  .then((json) => {
    if (!json.error) {
      return dispatch(sourceFindSuccess(json));
    }
    return dispatch(sourceFindFailure(new Error(json.error)));
  })
  .catch(error => dispatch(sourceFindFailure(new Error(error))));

// turn off spinner
return dispatch(decrementProgress());
};
}
```

Apologies for the wall of code but I think some context will help.  Anyway, if I go to:
`localhost:3000/acccount/login`
and I login, I see

`POST /api/authentication/login`

which is what should be there, however, if I type in

`localhost:3000/sources/SOURCENAME`

which uses the match param to pass down SOURCENAME to make an API request, I see 
`POST /sources/api/sources/find`

and likewise a call to 
`localhost:3000/sources/sourcelist`

gets me `GET /sources/api/sources/sourcelist` AND 
`POST /sources/api/sources/find`

which shouldn't fire but I realize now with the use of path= and not exact path= would cause it to fire both actions (I'll fix that now). HOWEVER if in the Route path I remove the /sources and reduce the paths to just `path="/sourcelist"` and `path="/:sourcename"` it works just fine.  So somewhere for whatever reason `/sources/` is getting appended to the Express route itself.  Anyone have any idea what's going on?